# How to set up the workflow for autopopulation of a list based on data in other list

Tags: list, workflow

I want to add items to a list based on columns from another list. 
For example, I have two lists: List 1 and List 2. List 1 has 5 columns; Name, Address, Manager, Phone, Email. List 2 contains 3 columns: Name, Manager, Phone.

When I add an item to List 1, I want it to automatically add a new item to list 2 and have the columns Name, Manager and Phone populated with the column values from list 1.

I have already set up the workflow in Sharepoint Designer to create the item in list 2 when item in list 1 is added. Currently my workflow has just one step "Create item in list 2 (output to variable: create) "

What other steps or actions do I need to create to get the lookup and autopopulation of the 3 columns in list 2 ? 
I am looking for detailed instruction please because I am new at SharePoint Designer and Workflow creation. Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

You define that in your instruction 'create item in list 2'. You should see something like this:
Use the 'add' button to add one of the list 2 fields, like 'Name'. Or select a field that's already there and click 'modify'.

[image: CreateItem]

Then, click the function button on the 'to this value', and from the current item, select the matching field.
[image]